# Onpopstate Function Only Working Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pushstate, popstate

On my website, when a link is clicked a jQuery function is run that loads content using AJAX and everything works well. I want to be able to use the backwards button in the browser to load the last AJAX request.

When I click the back button once it loads the last AJAX request correctly, but when I press it again, it just loads the same AJAX request and not the previous one. Here is my code:

```
$('.side-menu-link').on('click', function() {

    var data_url = $(this).attr('href');
    var post_title = $(this).attr('page-title');
    var post_url = data_url + " div.doc-content";
    $(".content-container").load(post_url);

    document.title = 'Website Name - ' + post_title;
    window.history.pushState({path:data_url}, '', data_url);

    return false;

});

window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    $('.side-menu-link[href="' + event.state.path + '"]')[0].click();
};
```

Any idea why this function only works once? Thanks

Comment: I think you overwrite the request every time, so always your last request is the same.

Comment: @Coli I suspected the same thing. What changes would I have to make to the code to fix this?

Comment: You can check if the last history entry is the same you want to set. So you can skip this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try...

```
window.onpopstate = function(e) {
    $('.side-menu-link[href="' + e.state.path + '"]').eq(0).trigger("click");
};
```